# Setup for running simple python scripts on (Nginx) web server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx, web-applications

I would like to run a couple of very simple Python 3 scripts on the web. As an example, say, the script just reads certain parameters from the URL, sends an email and prints out a simple HTML page saying "success".

I have a virtual private server with Nginx, so I am free to setup the best framework.

My question is: what is the state-of-the-art setup to do this?

More particularly: what do I need to install on my server for Nginx and what do I use in my Python scripts for e.g. reading the URL content? My idea is, that once the server setup is done, I can just put any new `script_xy.py` file into some directory and it can be accessed using the URL of the script, without a full blown deployment for each script.

**Flask** If I were to use Flask (or Django), each new script would need its own, continuously running process and its own Nginx setup. That seems like a total overkill to me. Another alternative is **web2py**, is it the same here or would that be an idea?

**CGI** 20 years ago I used to program such simple things as Perl scripts using CGI. I read this can be done in principle with Python, but CGI is slow. Then there is **Fast CGI**. However, my impression was that this is still a bit outdated?

**WSGI** WSGI seems to be the state-of-the-art alternative to CGI for Python. What python modules would I need to import in my script and what would be the setup for Nginx?

**Something else?** As you see, I might just need a few hints on what to search for. I am not even sure if I need to search for "Python web framework" or "Python server" etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot for your ideas!
juxeku

Comment: as i know `Flask` and `Django` use `WSGI` - so you have answer for question what python modules you need. And in any framework you can create function which get filename as parameter and use it to run script. But for the simplest server which don't even need `nginx` - `python -m http.server --cgi` and it will runs scripts which you put in subfolder `cgi-bin`. BTW: do you really need something faster then CGI ?

Comment: BTW: see [Full Stack Python](https://www.fullstackpython.com/)

Comment: BTW: state-of-the-art is to use frameworks like Django, Flask or similar but it doen't fit to your idea about putting `script_xy.py` in some directory without deployment.

Comment: Thanks! For these simple things I don't need anything faster than CGI. However, I want to avoid putting energy into learning an outdated way to do things. CGI would also need a setup on the server, so if there is a better way, I want to do it right from the start and put energy into learning things that I might benefit from in the future when I want to develop more elaborate things.

http.server might be an option, although the documentation says it shouldn't be used in production. Other options might be uWSGI or gunicorn?

Comment: `uWSGI` and `Guncorn` are used to server `Flask`, `Django` and similar frameworks. So you should put energy into learning `Flask`, `Django` or simillar.

Comment: Thanks! So my open question is about the processes. There is a [Tutorial on how to setup uWSGI with Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-uwsgi-and-nginx-to-serve-python-apps-on-ubuntu-14-04) for example. But if I understand correctly, for every app I need a separate process `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8080 --protocol=http -w app1.py` on the server, that runs the app on some port, here 8080, and then I would need to configure Nginx to forward from that port. For a second app, all that has to be repeatet, e.g. on port 8081...

Comment: ...Doing that for every new small app seems like a lot of deployment work and then I also have a lot of processes running on my server (the same with Flask or Django). So the question is: is there some way to setup uWSGI on Nginx in the following way: (a) a single uwsgi master process that is configured on one port in Nginx, (b) a folder with m apps `uwsgi/app1.py`, `uwsgi/app2.py`etc. so that (c) any request in the form `http://uwsgi.mydomain.com/app1.py` will be handled by one main `uwsgi` process, and (d) a new app can just be created by putting a new file into that folder?

Comment: I don't know any framework which can do it only adding file in folder. And probably you can't do this with `wsgi`. Only CGi cand do it. Even frameworks in PHP can't do this - only pure PHP without framework could do this.  All frameworks are created to help build portla with many apps which works together, not separated applications. Maybe put all in one Flask project. You can have `apps` in separated folders - Flask uses Blueprints for this - and it may need only one line in main file which starts Flask and you would have to restart server.

Comment: Eventually In Flask you can create function which uses `@app.route("(.*).py")` to catch url `http://uwsgi.mydomain.com/app1.py` and this function should run code from file `app1.py`

Comment: Thanks! I will read more about Flask and Blueprints, that seems to be a good approach!